# Change edge color of pgfplots patches

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting patches and do not want them to be colored according to their z-values. Instead, I want to define the colors by myself.

Here is an example:

```
\addplot3[area legend,patch,forget plot,patch type=triangle,color=red,opacity=0.8]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
x   y   z   c\\
0   0   0   0\\
0   0.3 0   0\\
0.3 0   0   0\\
};
```

I can override the color with color=red, but the edge color of the patches is still plotted in different Colors:

[image: Patch Plot]

I can't find the appropriate parameter to change them to black. Has anyone an idea of how to do that?

Here is a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      width=0.5\linewidth,
      height=0.5\linewidth,
      view={-213.5}{18},
      scale only axis,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=1,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1,
      zmin=0,
      zmax=1,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line*=left,
      axis z line*=left]

    \addplot3[area legend,patch,forget plot,patch type=triangle,color=white,opacity=0.8]
      table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
      x     y   z   c\\
      0     0   0   0\\
      0     0.3 1   0\\
      0.3   0   0.5 0\\};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will 'draw=<desired colour>' help? I cannot test this since you didn't provide MWE.

Comment: Sorry, I added a full example. Draw does not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the color of the edge lines by setting `faceted color=<color>`, or disable them completely by setting `faceted color=none`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      view={-213.5}{18},
      xmin=0,
      xmax=1,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1,
      zmin=0,
      zmax=1
      ]

    \addplot3[
            patch,
            patch type=triangle,
            color=red!25,
            faceted color=black
        ]
      table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
      x     y   z   c\\
      0     0   0   0\\
      0     0.3 1   0\\
      0.3   0   0.5 0\\};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the color can be specified with the c argument of the table. As changing the values for every triangle is quite tedious, a simple (but not very elegant) solution is to modify the underlying color map of the axis:

```
colormap={mymap}{rgb=(0,0,0); rgb=(0,0,0)}
```

Now every edge is drawn in black.

Comment: I see you've unaccepted my answer and accepted yours instead. Could you explain why you prefer this solution over the `faceted color` approach?